# htaccess rewriterule and directoryindex

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having issues with my rewriterule and directory index

```
DirectoryIndex invite.php about.php account.php

RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Lets say `about.php` is in the about folder. When i go to www.url.com/about/about.php, it works fine. But when I go to `www.url.com/about/`, it goes to my `user.php` page. When I go to `www.url.com/about`, (without ending slash), it goes to `www.url/about/?u=about`

Can anyone help me?

At the same time, I'm trying to set up where user can go to `www.url.com/andrewliu` instead of `www.url.com/user.php?u=andrewliu`

I guess I need to somehow fix my ending slash and the redirect?

Thanks!

EDIT

I have this

```
DirectoryIndex invite.php about.php account.php

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^b= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(business)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php?b=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: *"But when I go to www.url.com/about/, it goes to my user.php page"*, because you're rule does precisely that.

Comment: @JonLin why does it do that? i'm still new to this.

Comment: Your rule says: "match anything with numbers and letters and the _ and -", and rewrite it to /user.php

Comment: @JonLin oh ic. do you have a suggestion as to what I should do? based on the certain criteria I have?

Comment: @JonLin, actually, do you know why it messes up when I have an ending `/`?

Comment: It's mod_dir and mod_rewrite conflicting with each other. You could try `DirectorySlash off`, but not sure if that's what you're going to want to do, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a check to see whether the request is for a file or directory that exists. You need to add these conditions before your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

This makes it so when you go to `/about/`, since it's a directory that exists, this rule won't be applied. But if you go to `/andrewliu`, it will be as long as that's not a file or directory.

Comment: I have a slight modification of what you have, is that the reason why its not working?

Comment: @andrewliu what happened to the user.php rule? Did you delete it?

Comment: I'll show what I have total. I just wanted to let u know that I had that condition before

Comment: @andrewliu conditions only apply to the immediately following rule, so the ones you have **ONLY** apply to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`, you need these two above the user.php rule.

Comment: ahhhh that, I did not know!! Thank yoU!