# Conflict between RewriteRule and DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224189/htaccess-rewriterule-and-directoryindex) but it didn't help.
I'm trying to set a fallback file depending on the active project it is running.
If the project root has no `main.php` then it should fallback to `index.php`.
I've managed to do that using the following code:

```
DirectoryIndex main.php index.php index.html
```

But my problem is that I can't find a way to set the same rules to the `RewriteRule`. I'm trying something like this but it gives me a 500 error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . main.php index.php
```

How can I set a fallback in the `RewriteRule` so it works just like the `DirectoryIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^main\.php$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Your attempted rule has an extra dot in rule pattern.

Comment: I have this Rewrite rules and conditions so I can break the URL and route it trough the root index.php or main.php. Your solutions its treating all URL parameters as directories (ex: www.example.com/about/article1/ says article1 directory doesn't exists) and I need it to point either to main.php or index.php

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Can you clarify what is **same problem**? What URL you entered in browser and what problem you got?

Comment: For example, if I enter www.domain.com/en it should render my website in english but instead it gives me the error `Directory en/ not found`

Comment: Isn't that expected if `/en/` doesn't exist. How is `DirectoryIndex` solving this problem?